# My API Key is undefined even though it's in an .env file and a global var

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When trying to fetch data from an API, the key that I was using was considered "undefined". My key works because I replaced the {key=undefined} in the network console with the actual string and I was able to get the data that I needed. Any thoughts? Also, I know you shouldn't hide any API keys in a React app but I am just using this for testing purposes. If it helps to clarify things, I did use Create-React-App and they did have a major update in the last 3 months, so I wonder if that has anything to do with it.

```
     const bartKey = process.env.REACT_API_BART_API_KEY;
     console.log(`Api key: ${process.env.REACT_API_BART_API_KEY}` );

     //inside class Component
     async getAllStations(){
        try{
            const response = await fetch(`http://api.bart.gov/api/etd.aspx?cmd=etd&orig=${this.state.selectedStation}&key=${bartKey}&json=y`);
            // console.log(response.json());
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log('Initial data: ', data);

            // fetch(`http:api.bart.gov/api/etd.aspx?cmd=etd&orig=${this.state.selectedStation}&key=${bartKey}&json=y`)
            //     .then(response => response.json())
            //     .then(data => console.log(`here: ${data}`))
        }catch(e){
            console.log(`Error: ${e}`)
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does this entry look like in your `.env`? Is your `.env` in the top-level folder of your project?

Comment: Did you place it in the root of your project? I think you need to place `.env` file in /app folder.

Comment: did you setup this application with `create-react-app`? From what I remember they only use variables in the `.env` file if they start with the name `REACT_`. Maybe give that a shot and see if it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me when using create-react-app:

instead of `REACT_API_BART_API_KEY` use `REACT_APP_BART_API_KEY` in your .env

Then you can call it as `process.env.REACT_APP_BART_API_KEY`

check this url from create-react-app docs https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a really good solution if your .env file is working weird is to make a config file. Keep the API key in there. Put that file in git ignore and it will be hidden the same way and it is sure to work.

Answer (score 1):

**This changes helped me solve my issue:**

Please note **dotenv** is a zero-dependency module that loads environment variables from a `.env` file into `process.env`. So this you should at first download this package:

***1 step:*** `npm install dotenv --save-dev`

Import ***webpack*** and ***dotenv*** in your ***webpack.config.js*** file and make this changes:

After ***make sure module.exports an function which at first generates the environment keys***:

When the keys are generated use `webpack.DefinePlugin()` which will help you generate global constants for your app.

```
// other imports
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = () => {
    const env = dotenv.config().parsed;
    const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
        prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
        return prev;
    }, {});
    return {
        /* ... here should be your previous module.exports object attributes */
        entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
            filename: 'bundle.js',
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                template: "./public/index.html",
                filename: "./index.html"
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
        ]
    }
};
```

***Also note that on logging `process.env` you will still get empty object or nothing. But if you log `process.env.YOU_KEY` then you will get your key value stringified***

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score -2):

> As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

```js
require('dotenv').config()
```

You should write that line as early as possible in your program.

Comment: If you are using create-react-app you need not install dotenv. its already present through react scripts adding-custom-environment-variables. checkout this issue https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4485